# How to access shapefiles in OpenShift

Tags: file, openshift, classpath, shapes

I have shapefiles in my jar which is deployed in OpenShift. I'm able to access these files from my local environment by using "File sourceFile = new ClassPathResource("src/main/resources/CountryBoundaries.shp).getFile();". However, in OpenShift, my service complains that it couldn't find it. I have tried InputStream but I get an error in my IDE because the file is not a text file. Below is my code:

```
File sourceFile = new ClassPathResource("src/main/resources/CountryBoundaries.shp").getFile();
FileDataStore store = FileDataStoreFinder.getDataStore(sourceFile);
featureSource = store.getFeatureSource();
GeometryDescriptor geomDesc = featureSource.getSchema().getGeometryDescriptor();
attrName = geomDesc.getLocalName();
```

What am I missing? I'll appreciate any help as I've been struggling with this for quite a while now. Thanks.

Comment: No answers in the question, please. I have rolled back/edited your question and removed the answer. Add the answer in the answer section only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by changing URL to URI and then doing a toURL(). See below:

```
URI sourceFile = new ClassPathResource("PoliticalSubdivisionBoundaries.shp").getURI();
FileDataStore store = FileDataStoreFinder.getDataStore(sourceFile.toURL());
featureSource = store.getFeatureSource(); 
GeometryDescriptor geomDesc = featureSource.getSchema().getGeometryDescriptor();
attrName = geomDesc.getLocalName();
```

Hope this helps someone in the future. Shapefiles are complex and cannot be accessed the usual way like using inputStream and such. Cheers!